# Tensorflow 2: building an estimator with custom layer and tf.map_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to build an TensorFlow2 estimator from a custom Keras model. The model takes as input a tensor of shape [batch_size, n, h, w, c]. I need to apply a CNN on each [n, h, w, c] tensor from the back. To do that, I am using tf.map_fn:

```
make_model(params):
    batch = Input(shape=[n, h, w, c], batch_size=params.batch_size, name='inputs')
    feature_extraction = SomeCustomLayer()
    x = tf.map_fn(feature_extraction, batch)
    ...
    softmax_score = softmax(x)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=batch, outputs=softmax_score, name='custom_model')
```

When I compile and convert the model into an estimator, everything run fine:

```
model = make_model(params)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=metrics_list)
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(milcnn)
```

However, when I start the training, it fails miserably:

```
training_log = estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: training_dataset)
...
WARNING:tensorflow:The graph (<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7fa5ebbdf6d0>) of the iterator is different from the graph (<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7fa618050910>) the dataset: tf.Tensor(<unprintable>, shape=(), dtype=variant) was created in. If you are using the Estimator API, make sure that no part of the dataset returned by the `input_fn` function is defined outside the `input_fn` function. Please ensure that all datasets in the pipeline are created in the same graph as the iterator. NOTE: This warning will become an error in future versions of TensorFlow.
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/direx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2104, in make_initializable_iterator
    return dataset._make_initializable_iterator(shared_name)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute '_make_initializable_iterator'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

I am quite confused at this stage. My dataset is working perfectly with my model when I am using it directly as a Keras model. So, I expect it to be valid as well with the Estimator interface. Is the issue truely coming from a misuse of the estimator input_fn, or is it coming from the way I build the estimator or the Keras model?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue. I was initializing my dataset prior to the training loop:

```
dataset = input_fn(params)
 estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: training_dataset)
```

In fact, you have to directly pass input_fn as argument:

```
estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(params))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Helped me! I actually was also additionally having the function return train and test datasets. But that is not feasible with this limitation of having to return one dataset in the input_fn scope and also calling it while input_fn is invoked (for the graph to be the same as the model :( ). Guess we have to try to create the graph with some name at the beginning and pass it to all functions where tensors are created to get over with this nuance in the API.